# How to create an instance from function type declaration in typescript?

Tags: typescript, function, object

I have a declaration like below,

```
let f: { (): number; (page: number): void; };
```

How can I create an instance for this ?

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I have read this article, but I couldn't solve my problem. Making overload needs to be in function body, there are two functions, how can I make an overload two functions that have the same name ?

Comment: You're not describing two functions, `f` is typed as one thing that can be called in two different ways (which is going to make it quite difficult to actually use).

Comment: Your overloads are not compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
export type MyDelegate = {
    (): number
    (page: number): number
};

function foo(): number;
function foo(page?: number) {
    return page;
}

const f: MyDelegate = foo;
// or
const f2: MyDelegate = (page?: number) => {
    return page;
};
```